# Make Angular Material mat-select automatically take width of its selected option

Tags: angular-material, mat-select

How do I make  automatically take width according to its selected option's width? I've looked through the API of mat-select, and was not able to find an option/input for this.

Answer (score 2):

Just sharing a solution to the problem.  Here's how (turn ViewEncapsulation off or prepend these selectors with ::ng-deep):

```
.mat-select-value {
  max-width: max-content !important; // <= SOLUTION HERE...
}

.mat-form-field-infix {
  width: fit-content !important;  // <= and HERE...
}
```

[Playground with this fix](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5h6jd2-xmemtt?file=src%2Fstyles.scss)

Answer (score 0):

My Solution is something mixed with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72217168).
I took his code and modified it a bit, then in my Angular App I put the class into the styles.scss (This will be the outer most scss/css file you can find). And it works without `::ng-deep`

This is my solution:

```
.mat-form-field-infix { 
   width: fit-content !important;
   min-width: 200px !important; 
}
```

This solution is not very flexible though, thats why I would suggest you calculate the width in your script and set the elements width to that. it would look something like this:

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field [style.width.px]="setSizeOfDropDown(16)">
```

Typescript:

```
setSizeOfDropDown(fontSize:number):number{
let width: number = minWidth; //This is so that we dont have any codesmells
return fontSize * myOptionsArr.reduce((a,b)=>{
    a.length>b.length?a:b; //I used the shorthand if because it looks very clean
}).length
```

I multiplied the fontSize with the length of the longest string in the Array. and that is my Select width.